# How to create RBE2 between the end edges of a cylinder and end nodes of a beam element in ANSYS APDL?

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, ansys-apdl

I have a cylinder with shell mesh. on its axis I have a beam with the same length of the cylinder. I want to create an RBE2 between each end edge nodes of the cylinder and the corresponding end node of the beam. how is this possible using APDL ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `top_beam_n` is a component with the upper end node of the beam, `top_cyl_n` is a component with the upper end nodes of the cylinder, you can do:

```
cmsel,s,top_beam_n,node
*get,num_top_beam,node,all,num,min
cmsel,s,top_cyl_n,node
cerig,num_top_beam,all,all
```

[image: CERIG]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! but I would also like to know how to collect the end nodes in top_cyl_n and maybe also the beam

Comment: You could select nodes by location with a `nsel,s,loc,z,0` in `csys,4` with your workplane located at the top of the beam.

Comment: Thank you so much ! when I get the locations this way, will they also be put in the set named "S" already ?

Comment: You should check the help for the `nsel` command. The `s`in that case stands for "Select" and means that you _select_ every nodes where the workplace is located. If you want to separate the nodes attached the areas/lines, you can do something like `esll,s` and then `nsle,s` for lines, and `esla,s` and then `nsle,s` for areas.